# What is the adjoint of an inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, adjoint-operators

What is the adjoint of an inverse matrix? Is $(T^{-1})^{*} = (T^{*})^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $TT^{-1}=I$, we can take adjoints to find 
$$(T^{-1})^*T^*=(TT^{-1})^*=I^*=I.$$
So $(T^{-1})^*$ is indeed the inverse of $T^*$.